# Custom jQuery slider repeating the same image - not incrementing through 'i'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently it repeats the same images twice before transitioning. It seems like it's not incrementing through 'i'. How can I fix the jQuery so that it only shows each image once at a time?

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9DU5M/

```
$(function () {
                var i = 1;
                (function doAnimation() {
                    $('.slide' + i + '-img').css({ 'background-position-x': '-50px', opacity: 1 }).animate({ 'background-position-x': '-5px' }, 5000, 'linear').animate({ 'background-position-x': '0px', opacity: 0 }, 500, 'linear', function () {
                        $(this).attr('class', 'slide' + (i = i == 3 ? 1 : i + 1) + '-img').css({ 'background-position-x': '-50px', opacity: 1 }).animate({ 'background-position-x': '-5px' }, 5000, 'linear').animate({ 'background-position-x': '0px', opacity: 0 }, 500, 'linear', doAnimation);
                    });
                })();
            });
```

Comment: Not sure what kind of animation behaviour you are expecting but you are reseting background position during animation

Comment: If you look at the fiddle, the animation is correct (background position should just motion right slowly). However, it needs to increment through the next picture rather than repeat the same one twice each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have changed to the new image, you are showing it and then fading it out before you go back to showing it again. Just fade it in and go back to showing it:

```
$(function () {
    var i = 1;
    (function doAnimation() {
        $('.slide' + i + '-img').css({
            'background-position-x': '-50px',
            opacity: 1
        }).animate({
            'background-position-x': '-5px'
        }, 5000, 'linear').animate({
            'background-position-x': '0px',
            opacity: 0
        }, 500, 'linear', function () {
            $(this).attr('class', 'slide' + (i = i == 3 ? 1 : i + 1) + '-img').animate({
                'background-position-x': '0px',
                opacity: 1
            }, 500, 'linear', doAnimation);
        });
    })();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/9DU5M/1/

Note: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the background position. The `background-position-x` style is non-standard, and only exist in IE and Webkit browsers (Safari). You need to use the `background-position` style to make it work in more browsers.

Comment: Thanks! It doens't seem to work when I use background-position. Is this correct --> 'background-position': '-50px 0px'?

Comment: @BrentonThornicroft: That is correct if you use it in `css()`, but you can't animate composite values like background position without a plugin.

Comment: How can I make it animate without using background-position-x? What plugin are you referring to?

Comment: @BrentonThornicroft: The `background-position-x` style is not widely supported, so you would use the `background-position` style instead. As that takes two values, it can't be animated using the regular animation. There is at least one plugin for solving this, I found this: http://keith-wood.name/backgroundPos.html

Answer (score 1):

You have run the animation twice inside your loop..
Also, your condition statement in the last animation was late in checking..

I have tested this and it animates smoothly as desired same in your own fiddle...

```
$(function () {
            var i = 1;
            (function doAnimation() {
                $('.slide' + i + '-img').css({
                    'background-position-x': '-50px',
                    opacity: 1
                }).animate({
                    'background-position-x': '-5px'
                }, 5000, 
                'linear')
                .animate({
                    'background-position-x': '0px',
                    opacity: 0 }
                , 500,
                'linear', function () {
                    $(this).attr('class', 'slide' + (i = ((i+1) > 3) ? 1 : i + 1) + '-img');
                    doAnimation();
                });
            })();
        });
```